# Human Interface Guidelines for Contacts

Tags: ios, hig

Can anyone clarify or point me to an article from Apple explaining what messaging should occur if you are accessing the information in a user's address book and/or sending it to a remote server? Obviously there should be some sort of alert (similar to the one that grants location access) since this is fairly private data we are accessing, but I'd like to know when it should be displayed, and what it should include, if Apple has provided specifics on it. Thanks!